# How to know if a float got a decimals

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm building a simple calculator for a classroom, this is the code to show the result:

```
- (void)doTheMathForPlus:(float)val {
    float conto = self.contBox + val;
    self.myDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", conto];
}
```

I need to know if "conto" have decimals (to change the format of the string in a if statement)

how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (conto == (int)conto) {


}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, did you also know how to count the decimals?

Comment: Counting the "decimal places" in an IEEE floating point number is not meaningful. The number is not actually stored in a decimal representation, so for many values, the decimal representation is just an approximation. If you want to store numbers with fidelity in the decimal radix you should use a different data type.

Answer (score 3):

you'd better wrap that with `#define` and put this line in your `.pch` file

```
#define HAS_DECIMALS(x) (x!=(int)x)
```

than use anywhere in the code:

```
if (HAS_DECIMALS(conto)) {
    //number has decimals 
} else {
    //number does not have decimals
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dredful is right with his answer. 
And, You also can use different functions like floor, ceil, round. In You case better "floor(conto)".

But, you can't do like Kyr Dunenkoff suggested. becouse, all operands for"%" should be integer, but not float as "conto".

Comment: did you also know how to count the decimals?

Comment: 2 Marcello Cat,
as for me, I prefer to add small loop like 
while (!(conto == floor(conto))) { counter++, conto = conto * 10; }

Comment: Counting the "decimal places" in an IEEE floating point number is not meaningful. The number is not actually stored in a decimal representation, so for many values, the decimal representation is just an approximation. If you want to store numbers with fidelity in the decimal radix you should use a different data type.